# find the shortest path of travel from given route between vertices python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, shortest-path

> `x` travels different vertices. some path is given as input. input given as path between different vertices.

For instance:: `1-7 , 1-2 , 2-5 ,5-6`. By connecting this output would be finding the shortest path of travel output::`7->1->2->5->6`. i am new to programming. what logic i have to use?

Comment: Well, which shortest path algorithm did you implement? Where's your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most well-known algorithm for finding the shortest path, is Dijkstra's algorithm. You can find a python implementation [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466-dijkstras-algorithm-for-shortest-paths/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 2-opt algorithmn.